# Using Spinner in ArayAdapter invoke 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I'm creating an Android app. In it;

- A user is created
- When a successful user creation is done, the app shows another activity

Authentication and account creation works fine.

The second activity I create has a Spinner. This spinner is populated by the value in extra `nameDoctor`.

The Spinner works the first time. But if I press the back button or click any other button, (which used to work before adding the spinner) the app crashes with a NullPointerException.

The spinner should have a non-null value since it receives the value. But I am not sure where the NPE comes from.

I am new to android app developement if someone can help me PLEASE.

```java
    //code
    private void registerMedecin() {
       //code
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(doctor.email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new 
        OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isComplete()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Account.this, "Account creation error: " + 
        task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("doctor", "Account creation error: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                } else {

                    Log.e("Adddoctor", "user account created");

                    Intent sendNameIntent = new Intent(Compte.this, rdv_detail.class);
                    String name=nameDoctor.getText().toString();
                    sendNameIntent.putExtra("nameDoctor",name);
                    startActivity(sendNameIntent);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            SaveDoctorData(doctor);




                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

rdv_detail.java

```java
    //code
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rdv_detail);

        spinner_doc =findViewById(R.id.spinner_doctor);

        String nameExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameDoctor");
        ArrayList<String> spinnerData = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerData.add(nameExtra);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rdv_detail.this,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerData);

        spinner_doc.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);




}
```

Debug

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:457)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:419)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:206)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:614)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:428)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1204)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:723)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3006)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1833)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2122)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22413 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8624', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Hi, other user. The stacktrace seems incomplete - it must contain a line number in your own project. Can you show us where that NullPointerException starts?

Comment: so the value is null when your press back button ?

Comment: Please add the crash log and the screenshots of relevant screens.

Comment: thank you for your reply,I added the complete debug error...

Answer (score 1):

Caused by tryng to convert null object to string
 `String nameExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameDoctor");`

Please check before pass `nameExtra` to the array.

if it is not null comment to this answer.

`String name=nameDoctor.getText().toString();` should be empty when you reconnet by the same user. please check before pass it to extras.

Comment: I did if (nameExtra! = null) {// ArrayList.......} the app does not produce an error and at the same time the spinner is empty it retrieves no name

Comment: if i execute the first time it recovers the spinner when i reconnect by the same user the spinner is empty

Comment: ` String name=nameDoctor.getText().toString();` should be empty when you reconnect by the same user. please check before passing it to extras. Please give us more information about  **nameDoctor.getText()**.

Comment: hello, nameDoctor is the value I entered in a text field. I did if test to check if it is null if you can clarify me because I do not want it to be empty if I reconnect with the same user I want that each time I fill out the form the value of entered field is added to the spinner so that the spinner will contain at the end a list of several names that I have already entered.